# SQL NOT IN Function

Tags: sql-function, sql-in

Iam trying to insert a record and i want to check that it is not already present in the table.

I try

```
INSERT INTO emp (empno, name) 
VALUES(2, 'ram') 
WHERE empno NOT IN (select empno from emp);
```

but it shows error '`incorrect syntax near where`'

Comment: What SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following query to insert records into emp 
If you are inserting one record at a time then following query will work as best as it can ...

```
insert into emp (empno,empname)
    select distinct empno,empname
      from ( 2 empno, 'ram' empname ) as a 
     where  a.empname not in ( select empname from emp )
```

If you are willing to insert multiple records then just find below query

```
insert into emp (empno,empname)
    select max(empno),empname 
      from ( select 2 empno, 'ram' empname 
              union 
             select 3 empno, 'ram1' empname 
              union 
             select 4 empno, 'ram' empname 
           ) as a 
     where a.empname not in ( select empname from emp )
     group by empname
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have `WHERE` clause on `INSERT` statements, you have `WHERE` clause only with `SELECT/UPDATE`

If you work with MySQL, you could do something like:

```
insert into emp (empno, name) values(2, 'ram') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'ram'
```

And if you have a `unique` index on name column, you will be safe

Comment: so, how i can check for duplicate record before insert

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE` to fail silently if the row exists. It will attempt the insert, but if the key exists it will do nothing.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO emp (empno, name) VALUES (2, 'ram')
```

You might also want to take a look at [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

you'd probably be looking for something like

```
insert into emp (empno, name) 
SELECT 2 , 'ram'
FROM emp 
WHERE 2 not in (select empno from emp)
```

???

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the correct answer and ANSI SQL, AFAIK.